# Entered Text disappears when clicked elsewhere - Powerbuilder

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I do have a test field in one of my data windows. When I enter text in it and press tab, the value/characters entered are retained and the flow is going to the item changed event as well. But when i enter text and click elsewhere without entering Tab, the value entered disappears and the flow does not go inside the item changed event as well, since the entered value disappears.

Kindly provide your advice on how to retain the characters entered without giving tab out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger an AcceptText on the datawindow when it loses focus.  This then triggers an Itemchanged event for the field with the entered data.  The Help in PowerBuilder for AcceptText has examples of this.